# How to make a 8-by-8 matrix to 2-by-32 matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, reshape

I have `A` is an `8`-by-`8` matrix. I want to take the 6 last rows and put them next to the first and second rows so that matrix `A` become `2`-by-`32`.

EDIT :

```
A =

12,6872713121256    12,0602414786595    10,3270660536998    7,80915144314411    10,0045468077317    9,60906828665612    8,31320998311920    6,36510295973004
12,0602414786595    12,6872713121256    12,0602414786595    10,3270660536998    9,38969514490848    10,0045468077317    9,60906828665612    8,31320998311921
10,3270660536998    12,0602414786595    12,6872713121256    12,0602414786595    7,92932345092466    9,38969514490848    10,0045468077317    9,60906828665611
7,80915144314411    10,3270660536998    12,0602414786595    12,6872713121256    5,89043977575553    7,92932345092466    9,38969514490847    10,0045468077317
10,0045468077317    9,38969514490848    7,92932345092466    5,89043977575553    7,90694573827892    7,48897349750382    6,39213878381770    4,80849938907536
9,60906828665612    10,0045468077317    9,38969514490848    7,92932345092466    7,48897349750382    7,90694573827892    7,48897349750382    6,39213878381770
8,31320998311920    9,60906828665612    10,0045468077317    9,38969514490847    6,39213878381770    7,48897349750382    7,90694573827892    7,48897349750382
6,36510295973004    8,31320998311921    9,60906828665611    10,0045468077317    4,80849938907536    6,39213878381770    7,48897349750382    7,90694573827892
```

Dans solution gave not what I wanted , when I put this code : `Ry=reshape(A.',[],2).';`

I want to keep my first row and second row in there places , I just want to move the other lines (rows from 3 to 8) and put them next to row 1 and row 2 .. so that row 3 is next to row 1 .. row 4 is next to row 2 .. row 5 is next to row 1 and 3 ... row 6 is next to row 2 and 4 .. and so on ... Thanks

Comment: search for "how to reshape a matrix in matlab"

Comment: Regarding the comments below the answer from @Dan. can you provide the examples of both matrices?

Comment: yes man I will post them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `reshape` after transposing (necessary because MATLAB uses [column-major](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Row-major_order) indexing) to a 3D matrix. Then permute the matrix to swap the new third dimension with the second and then reshape and transpose back

```
reshape(permute(reshape(A.',8,2,[]),[1,3,2]),[],2).'
```

Comment: thank you this works Ry=reshape(R.',2,[]); without transposing

Comment: @Joe are you sure? Because if I think about it, surely it actually has to be `reshape(A.',[],2).' `. Check the actual numbers to make sure they are going where they need to.

Comment: I just did it in matlab and it worked as you siad but without transposing .. when I do transposing I get 32*2 matrix .. Just write in matlab `A=rand(8); B=reshape(A.',2,[]).' ; ` NOW SEE THE DIM OF B .. thanks

Comment: @Joe yes I know that. Look in my comment, I swapped the `[]` and `2`, it was a typo. Don't just look at the dimensions, look at the actual numbers inside and make sure that they have each individually gone where you wanted them to.

Comment: I see now .. I want to keep my first row and second row in there places , I just want to move the other lines (rows from 3 to 8) and put them next to row 1 and row 2 .. so that row 3 is next to row 1 .. row 4 is next to row 2 .. row 5 is next to row 1 and 3 ... row 6 is next to row 2 and 4 .. and so on ... your code did not do that ,, can you change it so that it do what I said now .. thank you man

Comment: @Joe I have updated my answer. It's a little more complicated actually. You'll need to get your head around 3D matrices and the order that MATLAB stores elements of it's matrices in memory (i.e. it counts down the columns)